# the project does not respond when the code executed

Tags: java, swing, runtime, processbuilder

No errors no output, can't understand where is a mistake.

```
String[] commands = new String[] {"maude", "in 1.maude", "red f(a, b, e) ."};
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec(commands);
InputStream stdin = proc.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line = br.readLine();
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    jTextArea4.append(line + "\n");
}
```

Initially, i have an array of a strings, the first runs the Maude Console, the second is the command for the Maude Console that says what is our module (file) that interests us (what file to load), and the last one is the actual command that check some property in the Maude Module!

Comment: Do you have to run the command via the "cmd" processor?  Can't you just execute the command directly??

Comment: Also are you respectinpg Swing's threading rules? Are you printing out Strings to the console to test that the program is working?

Comment: well, the last two commands are meant for the Maude Console. And if describing it in steps, we open CommandPrompt first, then running the Maude Console by passing the location of the *.exe to it, after Console is loaded we can give it a loading command such as "load or in 1.maude" "1.maude"-is the name of the module(file), after the file loaded we now can check the safety property (the last command in the code given above)

Comment: i've tried to replace `jTextArea4.append(line + "\n");`
 by `System.out.println(line);` and it runs until the Welcome Label of the Maude Console, so it seems that the Maude console doesn't accept or completely ignoring the rest of the commands

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
String maudeCommand = "full_path_to_maude\\maude.exe";
String[] commands = new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", maudeCommand, "in", "1.maude", "red", "f(a, b, e)", "."};
```

Replace `full_path_to_maude` with the location of the *maude.exe*.

Comment: i presume "cmd.exe" and "/c" no needed as long as we use runtime? isn't it?

Comment: however its still not responding

Comment: cmd.exe/c is needed. I assume you are running on Windows. Ok, I've updated the command. Are all characters in the command are correct & necessary - e.g. the last dot character?

Comment: right, ok! the last dot is important "that's the end of the command in the Maude Syntax", and the "in 1.maude" is also part of the command when calling the file from that console, but I was wondering I've tried the whole idea manually, running cmd first, then call the Maude console, loading the file and executing it with the command specified and it worked well...

Comment: Add in the full path to maude.exe (or bat file). See my update.

Comment: still no output returned, i've retried it step by step manually, just to make sure, worked fine...